How to better control JSON log output in Azure Functions 4.0?
Question:
I'm working on an Azure Functions 4.0 app and I'm facing an issue with the console logs. The logs printed in the console are not in standard JSON format, and I'm unable to have the same level of control over custom JSON output as I would in a web application.
In our platform, we collect and process logs centrally from the console. However, in Azure Functions, the log output is not easily customizable.
Is there a way to better control the JSON log output in Azure Functions? I would like to have more flexibility in defining the log format and structure.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I used Serilog JSON logging configuration, but it seems that the console output is not working.

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/78518622/2325216

Can you provide your code?

Was link/comment helpful, are you still looking for the solution?

Hi! An example of the JSON format you're aiming to generate will make this question easier to answer.

Thanks @Andrew B and I do agree that you can use program.cs to control the json, I do the same way and have followed SO-Thread:
Function.cs:
[Function("Function1")]
public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest rith)
{
    ri_logger.LogInformation("Hello Rithwik Bojja");
    return new OkObjectResult("Testing");
}

My program.cs:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Text.Json;

var rith = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(cho =>
    {
        cho.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        cho.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .ConfigureLogging(tst =>
    {
        tst.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
        tst.AddJsonConsole(cho =>
        {
            cho.IncludeScopes = false;
            cho.TimestampFormat = "HH:mm:ss";
            cho.JsonWriterOptions = new JsonWriterOptions
            {
                Indented = true
            };
        });
        tst.AddFilter("", LogLevel.Warning);
        tst.AddFilter("RithApp", LogLevel.Debug); 
    })
    .Build();
rith.Run();


